# Pandas - DataFrame manipulation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Csv which has data in different manner :

Data Set is given below

```
data = [[12,'abc@xyz.com', 'NaN', 'NaN' ], [12,'abc@xyz.com','NaN' , 'NaN'], ['NaN', 'NaN','x' , 'y' ] , ['NaN','NaN', 'a','b'] , ['13','qwer@123.com','NaN','NaN'],['NaN','NaN', 'x','r']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data , columns = ['id' , 'email','notes_key' , 'notes_value'])

df
```

Ideally third and fourth column should have the same id as first column.

The column name notes_key and notes_value represents the key:value pair i.e. the key is notes_key and its corresponding pair is in notes_pair.

I have to manipulate the dataframe in a way such that output turns out :

```
data = [[12,abc@xyz.com,x,y],[12,abc@xyz.com,a,b]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data , columns =['id','email','notes_key' , 'notes_value'])
```

I tried dropping the null values.

Comment: For `id=13` is not created row in ouput DataFrame?

Comment: If I add a new column lets say email which also shows the same behavior as Id column. The below-mentioned code fails.  
df3 = df3.replace('NaN' , np.nan)
df3['Name'] = df3['Name'].ffill()
df3['Email'] = df3['Email'].ffill()
df3 = df3.dropna(subset = ['Order-Note_attributes-Name' , 'Order-Note_attributes-Value'] , how = 'all')

Comment: Can you change data in question for see why code failed? There is no column `email`, so no idea where is problem.

Comment: Hello jezarel I have done the required changes.

Comment: I try solution `df3 = df3.replace('NaN' , np.nan) df3['Name'] = df3['Name'].ffill() df3['Email'] = df3['Email'].ffill() df3 = df3.dropna(subset = ['Order-Note_attributes-Name' , 'Order-Note_attributes-Value'] , how = 'all')` and for me working perfectly, added to answer.

Comment: What is the difference if I write the statement
df3['Name'] = df3['Name'].ffill() 
df3['Email'] = df3['Email'].ffill()
like this rather the format you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can forward filling missing values by `id` and then remove rows if missing values in both columns `notes_key,notes_value`:

```
#if necessary
df = df.replace('NaN', np.nan)
df[['id','email']] = df[['id','email']].ffill()
df = df.dropna(subset=['notes_key','notes_value'], how='all')
print (df)
   id         email notes_key notes_value
2  12   abc@xyz.com         x           y
3  12   abc@xyz.com         a           b
5  13  qwer@123.com         x           r
```